# What's the difference between these two code fragments?

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm working on this [Leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-longest-increasing-subsequence/description/). I cannot figure out the difference between my commented and uncommented code below. I'm returning an array at the base-case of a recursion, so when I call the `dp(i, prev)` function, the variable should hold the array with the two return values in it: length, number of occurrences (times).

Here's the code:

```
def findNumberOfLIS(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    @lru_cache(None)
    def dp(i, prev):
        if i >= len(nums):
            return [0, 1]  # [length, num seqs]

        if prev == -1 or nums[prev] < nums[i]: 
            # ****** HOW THE HECK IS THIS DIFFERENT FROM THE UNCOMMENTED CODE? ******
            # takeLength, takeTime = dp(i + 1, i)
            # takeLength += 1
            # skipLength, skipTime = dp(i + 1, prev)
            # if takeLength == skipLength:
            #     return [takeLength, takeTime + skipTime]
            # elif skipLength > takeLength:
            #     return [skipLength, skipTime]
            # else:
            #     return [takeLength, takeTime]
            
            take = dp(i + 1, i) 
            take[0] += 1
            skip = dp(i + 1, prev) 
            if take[0] == skip[0]:
                return [take[0], take[1] + skip[1]]
            elif skip[0] > take[0]:
                return [skip[0], skip[1]]
            else:
                return [take[0], take[1]]
        else:
            return dp(i + 1, prev)

    return dp(0, -1)[1]
```

Maybe I'm just exhausted, but I'm calling it quits. I even tried to have my wife, who knows nothing about programming, look at it (just to see if the two things reflected one another).

The commented-out code (`takeLength, takeTime, skipLength, skipTime`) works and passes most of the tests on Leetcode. I get a completely different answer with the code that isn't commented out (`take/skip`). I get a TLE with the working solution, but I spent the last two hours trying to figure out what I was doing wrong -- albeit, it's 3 AM, so I can barely type this.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: ```takeLength, takeTime = dp(i + 1, i)``` is the same as ```take = dp(i + 1, i)```?

Comment: Isn't something related to the mutable nature of Python list?

Comment: I can't see any fundamental difference, and both work on the 2 examples from Leetcode.

Comment: That said, lru_caching a function whose return depends on elements other than its parameters (nums here) seems dangerous to me.

Comment: @Swifty I was getting different outputs if I switch them out. With the code that uses indexing, I get result 8 for the first one (rather than 2). Also, could you explain further on lru_caching? I use that for DP problems without any issues.

Comment: @ewok One is storing index 0 and 1 into variables. The other is storing the return array into the variable and accessed later using the indices.

Comment: I tested dp as a function (that is, outside a class); dp(0, -1) gave the correct result [4, 2] with nums = [1, 3, 5, 4, 7], but after changing to nums = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4] it still gave the same result (because of the cache).

Comment: Now, discarding this problem, it seems indeed that with lru_cache the 1st code works (the first time at least), but not the 2nd code; I don't really know what happens, hopefully someone who knows lru_cache better can explain; however, I can confirm that without lru_cache, both codes yield the correct results. As @SRC mentioned, it's probably linked to cached mutable values.

Comment: I confirmed my latest assertion by adding `.copy()` in `take = dp(i + 1, i).copy()` and each time dp was recursively called: the 2nd code now works properly.

Comment: @Swifty Ah, I actually tried messing around with the copy function earlier on in my debugging, but forgot to try again after some more refactoring. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome; and if you want to keep lru_caching, add the list (or rather a tuple from it, since lru_cache needs your func to have hashable arguments) as a 3rd argument; that way the cached results will be associated to the list, and calling the function a 2nd time with a different list won't re-use na cached results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem with the 2nd (uncommented) code comes from using the cached mutable returns of dp, instead of unpacking them (which is the case in the 1st commented code). Making **copies** of these results solves the problem.

Another unmentioned problem is that `dp` is not reusable: the 1st time it's called, the return from dp(0, -1) will be cached and use in subsequent attempts (with different nums list); this can be solved by adding the numbers as a 3rd argument:

```
examples = [[1, 3, 5, 4, 7], [4,4,4,4,4,4]]

from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(None)
def dp(i, prev, nt):
    if i >= len(nt):
        return [0, 1]  # [length, num seqs]

    if prev == -1 or nt[prev] < nt[i]:
        take = dp(i + 1, i, nt).copy()     # the copy isn't really necessary
        take[0] += 1
        skip = dp(i + 1, prev, nt).copy()  # neither this one
        if take[0] == skip[0]:
            return [take[0], take[1] + skip[1]]
        elif skip[0] > take[0]:
            return [skip[0], skip[1]]
        else:
            return [take[0], take[1]]      
    else:
        return dp(i + 1, prev, nt).copy()  # this copy is mandatory

for nums in examples:
    print(dp(0,-1, tuple(nums)))

# [4, 2]
# [1, 6]
```

Note: actually making only a .copy() for the return is needed.

Comment: Nice analysis and answer!

Comment: Thanks; I had 'worked' on learning the functools module a few weeks ago; glad to see I remembered something :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need dynamic programming for this.  Keep track of the maximum size and count for each number encountered (in a dictionary) and use the previously computed size/counts to augment the largest size (and count) of each value.

Once all numbers have been processed, find the largest size in the dictionary's values and sum up the corresponding counts.

```
def lis(nums):
    nCounts = dict()
    for n in nums:
        size,count = nCounts.get(n,(1,0))
        if size == 1: count += 1
        for m,(s,c) in nCounts.items():
            if m>=n: continue
            s += 1                      # leverage counts of previously 
            if s > size:                # calculated smaller numbers
                size, count = s, 0
            if s == size:
                count += c
        nCounts[n] = size,count
    maxSize  = max(s for s,_ in nCounts.values())
    maxCount = sum(c for s,c in nCounts.values() if s==maxSize)
    return maxCount
```

output:

```
lis([1,3,5,4,7])   #  2            
lis([2,2,2,2,2])   #  5
lis([4,6,7,7])     #  2
nums = [0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,-109,-168,-112,-128,-116,-174,-175,-171,-162,-115,-122,-137,-142,4,-109,-100,-154,-183,-116,4,-177,-190,-150,-136,-146,-178,-181,-114,-186,-154,-155,-197,-142,-183,-134,-137,-122,-100,-198,-158,-103,-176,-149,-169,-147,-158,-106,-111,-199,-188,-172,-151,-129,-167,-176,-171,-185,-127,-172,-115,-102,-163,-195,-111,-105,-188,-118,-191,-122,-163,4,-159,-171,-196,-122,-196,-104,-176,-124,-123,-119,-155,-146,-194,-170,-185,-163,-102,-157,-152,-150,-154,-136,-172,-168,5,-177,-166,-122,-148,-118,-197,-152,-156,-121,-124,-104,-106,-153,-175,-184,-153,-180,-172,-135,-169,-100,-154,-183,-127,-105,-180,-114,-164,-158,-115,-133,-172,-149,-154,-155,-118,-187,-171,5,-158,-160,-192,-195,-200,-106,-197,-143,-160,-125,-133,-118,-148,-173,-188,-114,-199,-174,-104,-198,-114,-151,-116,-111,5,-144,6,-105,-178,-113,-108,-113,-141,-152,-172,6,-165,-160,-117,-165,-143,-198,-184,-135,-100,-144,-142,-152,-146,-153,-195,-134,-141,-136,-100,-100,-139,-195,-125,-170,-159,-137,-126,-122,-109,-134,-106,-132,-195,-140,-194,-151,-127,-110,6,-114,-134,-108,-148,-155,-118,-158,-138,-138,-148,-105,-134,-140,-149,-170,7,-177,-159,-126,-119,7,-154,-118,-178,-126,-167,-176,-123,-192,-155,-171,-183,-130,-123,-125,-166,-159,-105,-197,-111,-150,-177,-173,-103,-130,-186,-172,-167,-148,-168,-108,-139,-176,-116,-129,-154,-123,-127,-110,-106,-139,-175,-179,-100,-156,-186,7,-198,-199,8,-151,-180,-112,-151,-113,-174,-140,-143,8,-113,-120,-106,-173,-155,-190,-127,-131,-154,-146,-126,-148,-120,-133,-190,-109,-129,-169,-144,-101,-174,-107,-183,-109,-136,-161,-131,-145,-159,-186,-113,-169,-106,-195,-168,-138,-166,-115,-197,-164,-152,-188,-101,-126,-149,-124,8,-105,-173,-148,-144,-196,-155,-100,-175,-180,-113,-136,-158,-116,-190,-137,-146,-156,-194,-106,-121,-175,-122,-175,-176,-104,9,-146,-167,-200,-186,-195,-130,-176,-149,-134,-170,-129,-128,-158,-171,-185,9,-124,9,-181,-122,-101,-188,-174,-182,-112,-195,-114,-175,-161,-187,-127,-186,-169,-189,-128,-137,-108,-153,-186,-178,-186,-188,10,-155,-101,-135,-113,-141,-116,-102,-198,-128,-145,-190,-127,-108,-166,-116,-163,-181,-172,-148,-113,-191,-151,-123,-115,-135,-115,-144,-188,-129,-196,-105,-148,-112,-191,-160,-184,-120,-134,-149,-162,-174,-188,-134,-117,-175,-138,-192,-124,10,-180,-109,-130,-179,-154,-159,-177,-163,-160,-127,-147,-101,-134,-179,-133,-150,-168,-197,-145,-104,-122,-105,-189,-194,-152,-160,-110,-199,-196,-152,-187,-128,10,-198,-167,-180,-128,-111,-106,11,-151,-120,-156,-133,-132,-107,-183,-129,-133,-104,-106,11,-162,-136,11,-139,-133,-107,-192,-142,-196,-149,-169,-120,-198,-197,-165,-124,-198,-172,-115,-199,-130,-132,-164,-184,-106,-145,-130,12,-191,-115,-123,-169,-183,-107,-158,-124,-185,-116,-199,-184,-200,-125,-143,-135,-160,-170,-168,-155,-145,-171,-119,-139,-127,-127,-127,-189,-119,-179,-111,-100,-180,-135,12,-183,-136,-194,-191,-197,-168,-149,12,-152,-197,-156,-149,-130,-190,-107,-112,-199,-144,-186,-164,-141,-108,-199,-100,-173,-162,-159,-118,-176,-133,-107,-161,-182,-186,-179,-161,-190,-113,-145,-137,-169,-114,-178,-125,-116,-165,-196,-164,-163,-155,-121,13,-200,-170,-118,-133,-132,-150,-195,-132,-134,-148,-107,-137,-166,-138,-117,-182,-122,-176,-123,-171,-155,-151,-110,-181,-109,-129,-176,-178,-104,-128,-100,-108,-110,-169,-163,-119,-162,-174,-125,-102,-110,-170,-133,-119,-109,-110,-198,-153,13,-109,-160,-109,-111,-186,-126,-159,13,-111,-136,-140,-117,-122,-178,-182,-181,-104,-131,-126,-135,-103,-170,-180,-165,-139,-129,-126,-101,-141,-130,-119,-182,14,-122,-154,-148,-144,-129,-183,-122,-106,-185,-115,-196,-126,-112,-128,-157,-143,-106,-196,-198,-124,-184,-132,-190,-124,-121,-106,-106,-183,-153,-130,14,-181,-192,-179,-150,-179,-147,-122,-142,-151,-142,-129,-160,-191,-185,-140,-123,-134,-133,-180,-132,-169,-153,-192,-145,-195,-200,-150,-176,-164,-135,-112,-183,-193,-153,-101,-197,-125,-111,-116,-188,-119,-122,-175,-120,-198,-133,-106,-114,-143,-127,14,-145,-126,-171,-118,-147,-148,-155,-109,-132,-144,-125,-191,15,-124,-174,-129,-110,-169,-163,-165,-107,-114,15,-119,-114,-176,-141,-180,-135,-143,-131,-174,-165,-180,-131,-178,-129,-188,-108,-164,-195,-116,-200,-169,-162,-184,-122,-125,-165,-119,-149,-142,-120,-185,-148,-178,-107,-149,15,-145,-189,-164,-139,-139,-117,-111,-161,-154,-173,-135,-180,-138,-101,-169,-199,-160,-194,-125,-149,-134,-138,-164,-171,-121,-148,-157,-149,-187,-150,-180,-181,-156,-135,-120,-105,-135,-118,-142,-150,-142,16,-107,-187,-158,-186,-161,-138,-139,-142,-109,-135,-167,-159,-102,-190,-122,-144,-102,-117,-177,-158,-139,-125,-137,-148,-101,-182,-166,-142,-191,-173,-119,-173,-120,16,-140,-169,-119,-168,-156,-116,-198,-136,-128,-142,-174,-134,-156,-160,-145,-169,-189,-143,-190,-128,-133,-164,-175,-149,-141,-103,-179,-150,-138,16,-126,-107,-154,-116,-163,-199,-151,-185,-106,-186,-199,-198,-129,-188,-147,17,-183,-175,-159,-179,-181,-123,-186,-171,-189,-117,17,-136,-136,-135,-198,-102,-119,-128,-165,-199,-159,-180,-107,-142,-156,-101,-101,-175,-116,-179,-104,-149,-102,-199,-112,-159,-111,-128,-200,-181,-166,-130,18,-107,-148,-192,-155,-144,-172,18,-127,-122,-184,-193,-167,-108,-117,-147,-167,-104,-139,-136,-148,-187,-155,-112,-124,-133,-108,-155,-141,-170,-189,-139,-105,-166,-159,-171,-170,-113,-135,-177,-198,-103,-110,-189,-191,-143,-188,-189,-106,-134,-195,-151,-106,-108,-119,-106,-159,-191,19,-124,-166,-148,-174,-191,-145,-200,-183,-181,-197,-139,-115,-195,-180,-199,-138,-111,-150,-160,-163,-187,-176,-185,-188,-170,-160,-157,19,-104,-135,-151,-177,-124,-110,-143,-139,-182,-187,-131,-134,-140,-169,-148,-181,-157,-108,20,-129,-109,-139,20]
len(nums)          #  1103 
lis(nums)          #  1087680 (no recursion depth constraint)
```

Comment: That's a genius solution that I wouldn't have been able to come up with in an interview. I'm conditioned to seeing "longest increasing subsequence" and start thinking of a top-down DP solution (and eventually bottom-up), which should be a similar time complexity. I do appreciate the alternate way, though -- add it to the toolkit for interviews, whenever I may or may not get one.